# color filled bubble in plot function in R

Tags: r, plot

I have plotted a graph using the plot function in R. The bubbles that appear in the graph are hollow. I want the bubbles to be filled with color and if possible little bigger.

Here is the code:

```
    plot(risk_vector_nonagg,pch=1,type="p",col=ifelse(risk_vector_nonagg >= 1.1,   "#FF0000FF", ifelse(risk_vector_nonagg >= .5,"#FF8000FF", "green")))
```

[image]

Comment: `pch=16` for solid points. Use `cex=2` for bigger points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `pch` parameter. `pch=16` is solid. In the `Hmisc` package, you can see them all easily by calling `show.pch()`.

The cex parameter controls size.

Your code, with pch parameter added:

```
plot(risk_vector_nonagg,pch=1,type="p",pch=16,cex=1.5,
col=ifelse(risk_vector_nonagg >= 1.1,   "#FF0000FF", ifelse(risk_vector_nonagg >= .5,"#FF8000FF", "green")))
```